# Understanding Cantor's diagonal argument with basic example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm really struggling to understand Cantor's diagonal argument. Even with the a basic question. I proved that $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ in uncountable by defining:
$$
f(n)=g(n)(n)+1
$$
where $g\,:\,\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we get $f(n)=g(n)(n)+1$ so $f\neq g(n)$ (I don't fully understand this part but I agree, maybe the problem comes from here?). Then I tried to prove that $A=\left\{ f\,:\,\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\,|\,f(0)=0\right\}$ is uncountable, so I used:
$$
f(n)=\begin{cases}
g(n)(n)+1 & n\neq0\\
0 & n=0
\end{cases}
$$
But apparently it is wrong, I have to use:
$$
f(n)=\begin{cases}
g(n-1)(n)+1 & n\neq0\\
0 & n=0
\end{cases}
$$
But I don't understand why I use $g(n-1)(n)$ instead of $g(n)(n)$. What is the difference?

Comment: You haven't ruled out that $f \ne g(0)$. That's all.  We could have $g(0)(n) = g(n)(n) + 1$ for all $n> 0$

Answer (score 1):

The argument that these sets are uncountable is that we let $g:\mathbb N\to S$ be an arbitrary function and show that it cannot be surjective by finding an $f$ that is not in its image. So that’s why it works to construct an $f$ that is not the same function as $g(n)$ for any $n$.

So that’s what you must do in the second problem as well. As one instance, you need to be able to prove $f\ne g(0)$. In the second definition for $f$, you can argue this by letting $n=1$ and observing that then $$f(1)= g(0)(1)+1\ne g(0)(1),$$ so $f\ne g(0).$ In the first definition you gave for $f$ there is no way to make this argument, so it doesn’t work for this proof.

Note also that this is only one of many possible choices for $f$ that work.

Comment: It may be useful to add that one does not "have to use" the formula suggested, it just happens to be one that works.

Comment: @Andres yes I suppose calling it *the* correct definition is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem you are proving with this argument is that there does not exist a surjection $g : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$.

So, letting $g : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ be an arbitrary function, your job is to prove that $g$ is not surjective.

The method of proof is to use $g$ to construct something in the codomain $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ of $g$, which is not in the image of $g$.

In other words, construct an appropriate element $f \in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$, and use your construction to prove that $f \not\in \text{image}(g)$ which you do by proving that $f \ne g(n)$ for all $n \in \text{domain}(g) = \mathbb N$. That's exactly what you've written in your post: you've used $g$ to construct a specific element $f \in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$, and using the formula for $f$ you've proved $g(n) \ne f$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. So the proof is done.

Two further points:

- Although there may be many different elements in $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ that are not in $\text{image}(g)$, for this proof you only have to find one of them.
- To emphasize, once you've proved that $f \ne g(n)$ for all $n$, your job is done. You don't have to go on to consider that set $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't ruled out that $f(n)\ne g_0(n)$ if $g_0(n) = \begin{cases}0&n=0\\g_n(n)&n \ge 1\end{cases}$

To do the diagonal you hare saying that if you have a list $g_0, g_1, g_2, g_3.....$ that $f(0)$ willl..... well $f(0) = 0$ and will agree with all then functions at that point.  It's only for the values $n > 0$ that the function can differ.

So $f(1) = f(1)$ must differ from $g_0(1)$ and $f(2)$ must differ from $g_1(2)$ and $f(3)$ must differ from $g_2(3)$ and so on.....

Now I would see this as:  We want $f(n+1)$ to differ from $g_n(n+1)$.

But the person who wrote then answer saw it (equivalently) as: We want $f(n)$ to differ from $g_{n-1}(n)$ when $n> 1$.

So I would say:

Let $f(0) = 0$ and $f(n+1) = g_n(n+1)+1$.... which .. actually I guess at this point I'd come around to that person who wrote this answers point of view and as I want to express directly and $f(n)$ I'd write.... well I could *still* write:

If $n = 0$ or $n = m+1$ for some $m\ge 0$ then

$f(n) = \begin{cases} f(n) =f(m+1) =g_m(m+1) = g_{n-1}(n)& n> 0\\0& n=0\end{cases}$.

But at that point that's probably less clear and certainly unnecessary.